# NextJS 13 - How to use Localstorage

Tags: session, cookies, local-storage, react-context, next.js13

how can get data from `LocalStorage`/`SessionStorage`/`Cookies` to make
`initialState` 
of Context API in nextjs 13.

I tried calling locastorage in the client component `use client` but the problem is that it will render on the server and make localstorage `undefined`.  If you use `useEffect` to reset the data under `localstorage`, it will flicker when the page loads

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.